# How can I solve this coupled differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Can I please get a hint or two on how one would go about solving a system of differential equations as follows

$$\frac{dy}{dt}=ay(t)+ cx(t)
\\
\frac{dx}{dt}=bx(t)+ dy(t).$$

Any help/suggestions appreciated =)

Comment: Take a look into a textbook or find a source online. This is a standard linear ODE.

Comment: This question should be migrated to math.SE.

Answer (score 5):

For general linear ODE system
$$\newcommand{\b}{\boldsymbol} \frac{d\b{u}}{dt} = A\b{u},$$
where $\b{u} = (u_1,\dots,u_n)^T$, and $A$ is an $n\times n$ matrix. Then substitute 
$$
\b{u} = \b{\xi}e^{\lambda t}\tag{$\star$}
$$
back to the equation we have
$$
\lambda\b{\xi} e^{\lambda t} = A\b{\xi}e^{\lambda t}\implies (A-\lambda I)\b{\xi}e^{\lambda t} = 0.
$$
This says nothing but if the solution vector bears the form of $(\star)$, $\lambda $ will be an eigenvalue of $A$, and $\b{\xi}$ is the corresponding eigenvector. For your question, $n=2$, and $\b{u} = \begin{pmatrix}x\\ y \end{pmatrix}$.